# Casting an inner child class to another inner parent class outside the class

Tags: java, casting, inner-classes

Class B is inner class for A. Class B extends class C which is also inner class for A.

```
  class A{

     class C{

     }
       class B extends C{

       }

  }.
```

How do I cast an object of type C to type B from outside class A?
I was trying (A.B)objectOfC, but this does not work

---

Ok so the error I get is that java asks me to put ")" after "(A.". When I do that it says "Illegal start of expression.

Comment: Why are you trying to downcast?  (i.e. cast from a base class to a derived class)

Comment: I know that the object I am trying to cast is of type B, and I want to call a method on it, which is specific for class B(the child class) and not class C(the parent class). I cannot implement that method in C, bec then I would have to override it in the other classes that extend C, and i do not want that.

Comment: If you know you have an instance of `B`, then why don't you keep a reference to a `B`, rather than to a `C`?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: 1. I do not keep a reference bec. the object I am trying to cast, in my program is only once of another type (say D) that extends also C, and for the rest of the program is B. 

2. Generates error

Comment: Yes, but what error?  Please add the exact error message to your question.

Comment: Ok, can you also post the *exact* code that you're trying to compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class A {
    class C {}
    class B extends C {}
    B b() {
        return new B();
    }
}
public class So9961167 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a=new A();
        A.C b=a.b();
        if(b instanceof A.B) {
            A.B b2=(A.B)b;
            System.out.println("it worked!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this works inside class C, but outside, at the line:

A.B b2 = (A.B)b;

java says: ")" expected after (A.

Comment: I guess you are right! Is the compilers fault!!! I was using Dr.Java, jdk 5.0, and when I turn to Eclipse it works. Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to remember how casting works:

A child is like his parent -- because a child inherited from the parent.

A parent is not like his child -- because a parent inherits nothing from his child.

Therefore, you cannot cast C to B -- that's impossible in nature and in programming.

Comment: You can if the underlying object really is a `B`.

Comment: you can, I have done it inside class A and works, no problem. But when I am outside the class I am facing problem